# add conditional style to IE in drupal

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

I want to add conditional style sheet to IE browser.I have tried to add it in themes html.tpl.php file as

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="themes/themeName/css/ie_style.css"></link><![endif]-->
```

this file path is also correct but not included for IE browser.

Comment: Are you targeting any IE browser or specific versions?

Comment: targeting IE 9,10,11

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, It will target all IE browsers below VERSIONS of IE 7.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/themeName/css/ie_style.css"></link><![endif]-->
```